# How to Simplify Code jQuery($) .each

Tags: jquery, arrays, each, simplify

I'm new here and just start learning about javascript/jQuery, I have some codes that I made but I think it's not an effective ones, it's too long and kinda repeat the same thing, do you guys maybe could make a simpler code version of this one? Thank you.

Here I attach the html image:
[image]

```
        var sections = $('.section-page'), 
            sp = $('.sp'),
            sp2 = $('.sp2'),
            sp3 = $('.sp3');

        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            sections.each(function() {
                var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
                    bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
                if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
                  nav.find('a').parent().closest('li').removeClass('current');
                  nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').parent().closest('li').addClass('current');
                }
            });
            sp.each(function() {
                var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
                    bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
                if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
                  nav.find('a').parent().closest('li').removeClass('current');
                  $('#cssmenu > ul > li:nth-child(7)').addClass('current');
                }
            });
            sp2.each(function() {
                var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
                    bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
                if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
                  nav.find('a').parent().closest('li').removeClass('current');
                  $('#cssmenu > ul > li:nth-child(6)').addClass('current');
                }
            });
            sp3.each(function() {
                var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
                    bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
                if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
                  nav.find('a').parent().closest('li').removeClass('current');
                  $('#cssmenu > ul > li:nth-child(3)').addClass('current');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not really the place to ask for improvement of working code.

Comment: Oh, ok, thx for the notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function for the code that is repeated 4 times -- with some variations which you can cover by passing arguments to that function:

```
var sections = $('.section-page'), 
    sp = $('.sp'),
    sp2 = $('.sp2'),
    sp3 = $('.sp3');

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    function setCurrent(elem, child) {
        elem.each(function() {
            var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
                bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
            if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
                nav.find('a').parent().closest('li').removeClass('current');
                var li = child !== undefined
                    ? $('#cssmenu > ul > li:nth-child(' + child + ')')
                    : nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').parent().closest('li');
                li.addClass('current');
            }
        });
    }

    setCurrent(sections); // second argument not passed => undefined child
    setCurrent(sp,  7);
    setCurrent(sp2, 6);
    setCurrent(sp3, 3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimise in this way, and remember it,

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var sections = $('.section-page'),
        sp = $('.sp'),
        sp2 = $('.sp2'),
        sp3 = $('.sp3');

    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    sections.each(function () {
        var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
                bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
        if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
            nav.find('a').parent().closest('li').removeClass('current');
            nav.find('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').parent().closest('li').addClass('current');
        }
    });
    $(".sp,.sp2,.sp3").each(function () {
        var cur_class = ($(this).hasClass("sp") ? "sp" : ($(this).hasClass("sp2") ? 'sp2') : 'sp3');
        var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height;
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
        if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
            nav.find('a').parent().closest('li').removeClass('current');
            switch (cur_class) {
                case "sp":
                    $('#cssmenu > ul > li:nth-child(7)').addClass('current');
                    break;
                case "sp2" :
                    $('#cssmenu > ul > li:nth-child(6)').addClass('current');
                    break;
                case "sp3":
                    $('#cssmenu > ul > li:nth-child(3)').addClass('current');
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Give it a try, this should work.

Comment: far more efficient to cache `$(".sp,.sp2,.sp3")` outside the event handler since scroll can trigger many times a second and you are having to search dom each time

Comment: You are right :) Check my edited answer. You thought outta box. Thanks :)

Comment: that is opposite of what I was suggesting

Comment: I will give explanation, if I kept it outside of scroll and save it in variable, so changes to variable will happen i means to that DOM object. but if I directly apply this code without taking it in variable there wont be any issue. Hint, remember what we do at the time of clone, we take it in variable, and manipulate that variable so that original wont get affected

Comment: Thanks for the help @rahul, but it doesn't seem to work 100%, the var sections works well, but the var sp, sp2 & sp3 doesn't work, so it's like this:

there are 13 div with class="section-page", 3 of them also have class="sp", 1 one them has class="sp2" & 1 of them has class="sp3"

Comment: is your code working ? Because mine is just optimized version of your code, and you haven't mentioned in your question with some kinda problem as you are telling right now

Comment: Yes, my code above is working 100% (I separate sp,sp2&sp3 function), but when I try to combine 'sp','sp2'&'sp3' then it's not working. Sorry forgot to mention it

Comment: var cur_class = ($(this).hasClass("sp") ? "sp" : ($(this).hasClass("sp2") ? 'sp2') : 'sp3'); I have added this line, once again check